# How to remove improper nesting BBcode tags using PHP

Tags: php, regex, nested, bbcode

For some reasons I got the following improperly nested BBcode

[url=] Hello [url=] world [/url][/url]

I just want to remove the nested url tags. The result should be:
[url=] Hello world [/url]

I have a very long article and this happens many times. Any suggestions for this?

---

How to remove the nested tags happened many times in one article like this

[url=] Hello [url=] world [/url][/url] [url=] Hello [url=] world [/url][/url] [url=] Hello [url=] world [/url][/url]

Thanks!

Comment: Related: [RegEx match open tags except XHTML self-contained tags](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following tested script should do the trick. It uses a recursive regex and a recursive application of `preg_replace_callback()`. It will handle URL tags to any nested level and strips all but the outermost tags:

```php
<?php // test.php 20110325_1500
$re_url = '%# Match outermost [URL=...]...[/URL] (may have nested URL tags
    (\[URL\b[^[\]]*+\])       # $1: opening URL tag.
    (                         # $2: Contents of URL tag.
      (?:                     # Group of contents alternatives.
        (?:(?!\[/?URL\b).)++  # One or more non-"[URL", non-"[/URL"
      | (?R)                  # Or recursively match nested [URL]..[/URL].
      )*+                     # Zero or more contents alternatives.
    )                         # End $2: Contents of URL tag.
    (\[/URL\s*+\])            # $3: Outermost closing [/URL]
    %six';
function strip_nested_url_tags($text) {
    global $re_url;
    $return = '_handle_url_callback';
    return preg_replace_callback($re_url, $return, $text);
}
function _handle_url_callback($matches) {
    global $re_url;
    static $depth = 0;
    $depth++;
    $return = '_handle_url_callback';
    $matches[2] = preg_replace_callback($re_url, $return, $matches[2]);
    if ($matches[2] === NULL)
    { // On error, preg_replace_callback returns NULL.
        exit('Error - Message is too long or too complex.');
    }
    if (--$depth > 0) return $matches[2];
    return $matches[1] . $matches[2] . $matches[3];
}
$data = file_get_contents('testdata.html');
$data = strip_nested_url_tags($data);
file_put_contents('testdata_out.html', $data);
?>
```

Comment: Hi ridgerunner. Can I ask you how to study regular expression and where to start?

Comment: @Don: Yes! Read: [Mastering Regular Expressions (3rd Edition)](http://www.amazon.com/Mastering-Regular-Expressions-Jeffrey-Friedl/dp/0596528124) By Jeffrey Friedl. It is a great tutorial (even funny) and it takes you from beginner to advanced levels. The [SlashDot review](http://news.slashdot.org/story/06/09/13/147213/Mastering-Regular-Expressions) rated it _11 out of 10!_ And I wholeheartedly agree - Best book on Regex - ever!

Comment: @ridgerunner Great solution. Could you possibly suggest any adjustments to remove the content inside the nested URL tags i.e. `[URL=http://site1/]text before [URL=http://site2/]site2[/URL]text after[/URL]` becomes `[URL=http://site1/]text before text after[/URL]`

Comment: @Sooper - To remove the content from URL tags nested inside other URL tags (in addition to the nested start and end BBCode tags), simply change the second to last line in: `_handle_url_callback()` function to read: `if (--$depth > 0) return "";`

Comment: @ridgerunner your sir, are a delight.

Answer (score 0):

This might work:

```
$string = preg_replace("/(\[url=[^\]]*\].*)\[url=[^\]]*\](.*)\[\/url\](.*\[\/url\])/is", "$1$2$3", $string);
```

You should find the root of the problem rather than trying to undo it, though.

Comment: I know the reason of the problem but I can not modify previous codes. Thanks!

Comment: Hi TVK, if i have more than one nested problems like this "[url=] Hello [url=] world [/url][/url] [url=] Hello [url=] world [/url][/url] [url=] Hello [url=] world [/url][/url]". How to correct all of them? I tried your codes but only remove the last one.

Comment: Hmmm, maybe this works: `$string = preg_replace("/(\[url=[^\]]*\](^(\[url=))*)\[url=[^\]]*\](.*)\[\/url\](.*\[\/url\])/is", "$1$4$5", $string);` (Edit: Ups made an error. Updated it.)